# Why does assigning default value to a var in Scala prevent compilation errors?

Tags: scala

I'm running into the following piece of code:

```
abstract class CommonThing {
   var lookupTable: Map[String, Double] = _

   // ....
   // sets up base configurations
}

class FinalThing extends CommonThing {
   // generates actual production data
}
```

If I remove the default assignment to lookupTable, I get a compile error saying `FinalThing` should implement `lookupTable`.  However, it's not being used by `FinalThing`.

Why am I getting that error, and is there a better way to code this so I don't have to add a default value to the base 'lookupTable'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in scala `var` fields are considered abstract if they do not have implementation. If you omit the implementation in `CommonThing` for `lookupTable`, then `lookupTable` is believed to be abstract and is required to be implemented in `FinalThing` because it is concrete (not abstract) class.

Answer (score 1):

If `FinalThing` is not using the `lookupTable` it means there is a problem in your class hierarchy design.

Here is an attempt to give a better solution (warning: I don't know what you are trying to do so this might be quite off):

```
trait CommonThingsBase {
   // ....
   // sets up base configurations
}

trait LookUpTableLogic {
   var lookupTable: Map[String, Double]
}

abstract class CommonThing extends CommonThingsBase with LookUpTableLogic {
   var lookupTable: Map[String, Double] = _
   // Code that uses the lookupTable
}

class FinalThing extends CommonThingsBase {
   // generates actual production data
}
```